# Application that simulates copy/paste doesn't work after being sandboxed. How to get it working?

Tags: xcode, macos, cocoa, macos-carbon

I am building an application that simulates user input (command+c and command+v). Before sandboxing it, everything worked fine, but now I am getting these errors from the console:

Firstly, when I fire it up:

> 5/27/13 1:35:11.980 AM appleeventsd[54]:  A sandboxed application with pid 5343, "CopyBoard" checked in with appleeventsd, but its code signature could not be validated ( either because it was corrupt, or could not be read by appleeventsd ) and so it cannot receive AppleEvents targeted by name, bundle id, or signature. Error=ERROR: #100013  { "NSDescription"="SecCodeCopyGuestWithAttributes() returned 100013, -." }  (handleMessage()/appleEventsD.cp #1755) com.apple.coreservices.appleevents.peer.0x7fa9b0411260.xpcq

Then, when I try to simulate command+c, I get:

> 5/27/13 1:52:22.980 AM WindowServer[85]: post_filtered_event_tap_data: Sender is prohibited from synthesizing events
>
> 5/27/13 1:52:23.000 AM kernel[0]: Sandbox: sandboxd(6515) deny mach-lookup com.apple.coresymbolicationd
>
> 5/27/13 1:52:24.252 AM sandboxd[6515]: ([5343]) CopyBoard(5343) deny hid-control

I'm looking for a solution that would allow me to copy and paste globally in a sandboxed environment. Is it possible that the Accessibility API is a good answer? Has my problem got anything to do with how I'm simulating user input? I'm very confused, thank you very much for helping.

Answer (score 1):

The sandbox is designed to prevent exactly what you seem to be trying - allowing an application to simulate a user is defined as a security issue. If you have a narrow requirement which can be done safely you can submit it to Apple thorough bug reporter as an needed improvement to the sandbox.

The Accessibility API is not supported in general for this reason - no playing with other apps! This did not go down so well with all the developers which used it...

You can use AppleEvents in limited constrained circumstances and with the appropriate entitlements.

You'll probably need to go to developer.apple.com and read all the documents/view videos/etc you can find to see if what you wish is going to be possible.

The only point of hope I can offer you is that the sandbox is a moving target, so you may find you can do more than the above suggests. Go read. Good luck.

Comment: Darn it :/ Thank you very much, I'll check it out. Do you think there's anything wrong with my code signature due to the first error?

Comment: @AlfieSubiotto - It looks like you have some sort of issue with the code signature preventing the app from receiving AEs (which is separate from sending them). That's a different issue from the other errors which are related to the sandbox disallowing actions.